# How long after withdrawing Finasteride hair loss starts again?

Tags: hairloss

How long does it take for hair loss to resume after stopping finasteride?

Comment: I edited your question to make it general and not a request for medical advice. If you disagree with my edits you can revert them, but that will make your question off topic.

Comment: Adding some more context in the sense of 'your prior research' would increase the quality. Currently it's low.

Comment: Took me 3 weeks to see a noticeable increase in hair loss. I know one case report can't be an "answer", but I thought it might be helpful to share this information.